# Running npm run eject to use css modules

Tags: reactjs, npm, package.json

On running the command **npm run eject**, I should get two files in the **config** named **webpack.config.prod** and **webpack.config.dev** to modify css loader. But, I didn't get them. What might be the problem?

Answer (score 2):

You have to follow some steps:
1. **git add .**

2. You must have to commit before install eject: 
   **git commit -m "some msg"**
3. run eject:
   if you use yarn, you should type on your terminal: 
   **yarn eject**
   or
   **npm run eject**
4. one config folder will be added to your project, and inside this folder, you will find one file called "**webpack.config.js**".
   searching "css-loader" or type **(Ctrl+f)** for searching specific words.
   you will find below code in this file.

   ```js
   {
      loader: require.resolve('css-loader'),
      options: cssOptions,      
   }
   ```

change it by:

```
{
   loader: require.resolve('css-loader'),
   options: {
      modules: {
        mode: "local",
        localIdentName: "[name]_[local]_[hash:base64:5]"
      },
      import: true,
      importLoaders: true
    }     
}
```

**5. the most important part is now you must restart your code editor, sometimes it can be 4/5 times.**

these upper steps worked for me.
hopefully, it will also work for you.
**Enjoy...............**

Answer (score 1):

You should be getting `config/webpack.config.js` that you could split into two if you want. But you could also use the env to conditionally set your loaders. Take a look at `const configFactory = require('../config/webpack.config');` and `const config = configFactory('development / production');` in the `build.js` and `start.js` scripts.

You might not need to eject: Create React App 2+ supports TypeScript, Sass, CSS Modules and more without ejecting: https://reactjs.org/blog/2018/10/01/create-react-app-v2.html